# Having Multiple WebViews or Importing Java Libraries

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, webview

I am fairly new to the Android Development. I am just learning all about it but thanks to my web programming background it is being really fast.

I have a question about webviews. When I have a simple component (like a chart) but hard to draw with Java I am building it with HTML and CSS and using it as a webview.

My question can look like opinion based but I am asking this in terms of performance.

I am wondering, how is having couple of simple webviews affects performance? I know that there is libraries almost for everything but importing a big library for a simple chart or something else seems like an overkill to me when I can make it with ~50 lines of HTML and CSS code.

Which one is more powerful? WebView or importing libraries for everything?

Answer (score 2):

I guess importing libraries are much better for performance because those are you know stored locally whereas mostly web-views are very slow and unresponsive but if you don't have technical skills to work with library you can go with webview but in future try to use any library or you can take help of youtube there are lots of videos which teach you how to do

Maybe video like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWBA2ikLJjU